# virtualbox ERROR

Tags: debian, virtualbox, whonix

hi I'm using Debian 10 and trying to run whonix on virtualbox
but when run its two modules throws an error:
"fail in opening sesion"

details:
"VT-x is disabled in the Bios for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)"

result code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)

component: ConsoleWrap

interfaz: IConsole
{872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

and in terminal:

"Qt WARNING  : QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'

know what i must to do to run it?
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Virtualisation / RAM related issue. The documentation is self explanatory:

> You are trying to allocate >3GB of RAM to the VM. This requires: (a) a
>   64 bit host system; and (b) true hardware pass-through ie VT-x.

**Fast solution**

Allocate less than 3GB for the virtual machine.

**Complete solution**

1. Make sure your system is 64 bit.
2. Enable virtualisation in your host machine. You can find how to do it [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/) or there are many other resources available on [Google](https://www.google.es/#safe=off&q=Enable+virtualization+in+your+computer).